# Is there a way to cache data between calls to the same UDF in an XLL generated using ExcelDNA?

Tags: c#, excel

I am building an Excel XLL add-in (using ExcelDNA) to manage data imports to a collection of Excel calculations, and am getting confused by the calling structure for UDFs. What I want to achieve (and the old VBA version of the tool does achieve) is:

1. A UDF in C# that can be called from Excel cells (this is working).
2. Said UDF needs to check whether some cached data (in C# XLL memory space) is available (this is what is confusing me).
3. If cached data is available, the UDF needs to retrieve this, otherwise it needs to do something else (to get the data and cache it). (this is not working, but I assume will be self-evident once I crack number 2)

My UDF code (massively simplified to the points of interest) is:

```csharp
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class MyFunctions
{
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Get Data function")]
    public static string GetEBData(string name)
    {
        string filename = <some code to get the caller FullName - TBC>;
        Dictionary<string, Data_Tool.DataCache> calcs;
        if (!calcs.ContainsKey(filename)) calcs.Add(filename, new Data_Tool.DataCache(filename));

        //<some code to get the result from the Dictionary or elsehwere>
        return result;
    }
}
```

I do not think the location of the Dictionary definition is correct, as it should somehow exist outside the specific UDF call (the UDF call should just be able to 'see' that Dictionary and check for the items within it - essentially it is a dictionary with each Excel workbook filepath as the key). But where would I put that Dictionary definition and assignment?
I also get an error at present because I am using 'calcs' unassigned when I check for null.

Obviously my class Data_Tool.DataCache is taking a filename as the constructor argument, and I want to build a Dictionary of these object instances for each Workbook that is open and using the XLL UDF.

What I am essentially missing is what code runs 'at a higher level' than the UDF definition itself, if that makes sense?
I also wonder as a bonus question whether anyone knows how to get the Workbook.FullName property from the cell that called the UDF using ExcelDNA? I cannot get on the Google Groups forums from my work PC, so am unable to look there.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed the answer. Seems to be that I can declare a static Dictionary outside the UDF like so:

```csharp
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class MyFunctions
{
    static Dictionary<string, Data_Tool.DataCache> calcs = new Dictionary<string, Data_Tool.DataCache> { };

    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Get Data function")]
    public static string GetEBData(string name)
    {
        string filename = <some code to get the caller FullName - TBC>;
        if (!calcs.ContainsKey(filename)) calcs.Add(filename, new Data_Tool.DataCache(filename));

        //<some code to get the result from the Dictionary or elsehwere>
        return result;
    }
}
```

I now just need to make sure objects get removed from the Dictionary when the file is closed or the cache expires; but essentially I think there is a way forward.

Also worked out how to get the caller filepath using a helper function:

```csharp
private static string CallerName()
{
    ExcelReference caller = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller);
    string sheetName = (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlSheetNm, caller);
    return System.IO.Path.Combine((string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGetDocument, 2, sheetName), (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGetDocument, 88, sheetName));
}
```